# Xamarin: Binding to ImageSource property is not working

Tags: xamarin, binding, imagesource

I am trying to display images dynamically through binding:

I have ObservableCollection of TabItem to which I load a png into the Icon Property:

```
TabItems.Add(new TabItem()
{
    Title = AppResources.Home,
    IsSelected = true,
    Icon = ImageSource.FromResource("Home.png")
});
```

Where:

```
public class TabItem : BindableObject
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a DataTemplate of TabItem in a CollectionView that displays these items and uses the Icon Property to bind to Image:

```
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TabItem" x:Key="TabItem_DataTemplate">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     WidthRequest="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource ProportionateConverter}}"
                     >
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" InputTransparent="True" HeightRequest="50" />
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="Small"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                   InputTransparent="True" 
                   TextColor="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToTextColorConverter}}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I get an Error in runtime:

```
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

The images are in the Resources folder and are marked as Embedded resource

**Updated solution:**
(Thanks Jason)

The solution was using my markup extension when initializing the Icon property (I'll be glad to hear of a more elegant way)

```
var homeExt = new ImageResourceExtension()
{
    Source = "TimeManager.Resources.Icons.Home.png"
};

TabItems.Add(new TabItem()
{
    Title = AppResources.Home,
    IsSelected = true,
    Icon = (ImageSource)(homeExt.ProvideValue(null))
});
```

Comment: change Icon to a string containing the resource name

Comment: When I do that I get: FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: Home.png

Comment: if you hardcode `Source="Home.png"` in your XAML does it work?  If not, there is a problem with your images you need to fix first

Comment: No, same error here. But when I use my markup extension it works: <Image Source="{extensions:ImageResource TimeManager.Resources.Home.png}"

Comment: if your image in the resources of the **shared** project?  If so, then you will have to combine binding the resource name as a string with your extension

Comment: Thanks Jason! That's it. The combination between the markup extension and the resource name worked. I have edited my post to add the solution.